# "query function not defined for Select2 undefined error"

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, jquery-select2

Trying to use Select2 and getting this error on multiple item input/text field:

```
"query function not defined for Select2 undefined error"
```

Answer (score 250, accepted):

[Covered in this google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/lGNVfAmVIxg)

> The problem was because of the extra div that was being added by the select2. Select2 had added new div with class "select2-container form-select" to wrap the select created. So the next time i loaded the function, the error was being thrown as select2 was being attached to the div element. I changed my selector...

Prefix select2 css identifier with specific tag name "select":

```
$('select.form-select').select2();
```

Comment: somehow fixed it for me, in my case I was cloning a row of form inputs which included select2-ified select menus and all sorts of weird stuff was happening after the first clone.

Comment: Also has to be inside `$(document).ready(function() { $('select.form-select').select2()})`

Comment: How can the same problem be solved in Angular UI Select2 directive?

Comment: Just came across this same problem today - although the same code previously had no issues (perhaps an update of select2?).  Anyways, this solved it for me as well and working fine again.  Great answer!

Comment: This problem usually happens if the select control has already been initialized by the `.select2({})` method. A better solution would be calling the destroy method first. Ex: `$("#mySelectControl").select2("destroy").select2({});`

Comment: @zavidovych, to solve this in Angular2 for select2 You can initialize select2 it in ngOnInit() and destroy select2 it on ngOnDestroy().

So, in ngOnInit() {jQuery('.chzn-select').select2();}
ngOnDestroy(){jQuery('.chzn-select').select2('destroy');}

of course, you have to declare as  declare var jQuery: any;

Comment: > $("#mySelectControl").select2("destroy")

Is there a way to reconfigure select2 dynamically?

Answer (score 19):

This error message is too general. One of its other possible sources is that you're trying to call `select2()` method on already "select2ed" input.

Answer (score 15):

In case you initialize an empty input do this:

```
$(".yourelement").select2({
 data: {
  id: "",
  text: ""
 }
});
```

Read the first comment below, it explains why and when you should use the code in my answer.

Comment: I had this problem when I migrated a select2 box from an actual select element to a input type=hidden element that I was populating later.  In stepping through the select2 code, this error is thrown because there is no query, ajax, data, or tags value passed in.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question. Not sure why `select2()` won't simply just accept empty parameters

Answer (score 12):

I also had this problem make sure that you don't initialize the select2 twice.

Comment: same for me, but the error wasn't a problem to me. s2 works anyway

Comment: how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

For me this issue boiled down to setting the correct data-ui-select2 attribute:

```
<input type="text" data-ui-select2="select2Options.projectManagers" placeholder="Project Manager" ng-model="selectedProjectManager">


$scope.projectManagers = { 
  data: []  //Must have data property 
}

$scope.selectedProjectManager = {};
```

If I take off the `data` property on `$scope.projectManagers` I get this error.

Answer (score 5):

This issue boiled down to how I was building my select2 select box. In one javascript file I had...

```
$(function(){
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```

And in another js file an override...

```
$(function(){
    var employerStateSelector = 
                $("#registration_employer_state").select2("destroy");
    employerStateSelector.select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a State...'
    });
});
```

Moving the second override into a window load event resolved the issue.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  var employerStateSelector = 
              $("#registration_employer_state").select2("destroy");
  employerStateSelector.select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a State...'
  });
});
```

This issue blossomed inside a Rails application

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same error when using ajax with a textbox then i solve it by **remove class select2** of textbox and setup select2 by id like:

```
$(function(){
  $("#input-select2").select2();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your selector returns an undefined element (Therefore `undefined error` is returned)

In case the element really exists, you are calling select2 on an `input` element without supplying anything to select2, where it should fetch the data from. Typically, one calls `.select2({data: [{id:"firstid", text:"firsttext"}])`.

Answer (score 2):

Also got the same error when using ajax.

If you're using ajax to render forms with select2, the input_html class must be different from those NOT rendered using ajax. Not quite sure why it works this way though.

Comment: You mean like, "<input type='hidden' class='foo' ...." where if you have multiple select2's, they can't all be 'foo'? This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof(opts.query) !== "function") {
    throw "query function not defined for Select2 " + opts.element.attr("id");
}
```

This is thrown becase query does not exist in options. Internally there is a check maintained which requires either of the following for parameters

- ajax
- tags
- data
- query

So you just need to provide one of these 4 options to select2 and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I have been using select2-3.5.2

This was my code which had error

```
    $('#carstatus-select').select2().val([1,2])
```

Below code fixed the issue.

```
    $('#carstatus-select').val([1,2]);
```

Comment: I would use  $('#carstatus-select').select2("val", [1,2]); as mention in the docs

Answer (score 0):

I have a complicated Web App and I couldn't figure out exactly why this error was being thrown. It was causing the JavaScript to abort when thrown.

In select2.js I changed:

```
        if (typeof(opts.query) !== "function") {
            throw "query function not defined for Select2 " + opts.element.attr("id");
        }
```

to:

```
        if (typeof(opts.query) !== "function") {
            console.error("query function not defined for Select2 " + opts.element.attr("id"));
        }
```

Now everything seems to work properly but it is still logging in error in case I want to try and figure out what exactly in my code is causing the error. But for now this is a good enough fix for me.