# select2 jquery plugin not working after ajax calling for HTML content change

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

i did called ajax function for html div change, In that div change content have 'select2' jquery class to select box. After ajax loaded that select2 jquery plugin not working properly.

This my js:

```
$('body').on('click', '.portlet > a.reloadcontent', function(e) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      url: url,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(res) {
          $('#colpart').find('.portlet-body').html(res);
      }
   });
});
```

This my HTML:

```
<div id="#colpart">
    <a href="#" data-url="columnspage.html" class="reloadcontent" data-load="true">Columns</a>
    <div class="portlet-body"></div>
</div>
```

columnspage.html

```
<select class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="1">Column 1</option>
 </select>
```

select2me class for select2 jquery plugin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674228/select2-jquery-plugin-not-working-after-ajax-calling-for-html-content-change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674228/select2-jquery-plugin-not-working-after-ajax-calling-for-html-content-change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674228/select2-jquery-plugin-not-working-after-ajax-calling-for-html-content-change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize select after success callback, because your drop down is added dynamically in DOM,

```
success:function(res){
   $('#colpart').find('.portlet-body').html(res);
   // reinit your plugin something like the below code.
   $('.select2me').select2();
}
```

Comment: Try to add your element in your page directly and call it (without using ajax) and check, don't forget to check your console for errors.

Comment: It shows "uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2 s2id_autogen1" in console

Comment: i need to call only by ajax function.

Comment: Ok, once you get called it from static page then you can change it with ajax also. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483348/query-function-not-defined-for-select2-undefined-error

Comment: i have solved it by remove class name to id name. thanks

Comment: really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax success function you need to initialize the select.

Example:

```
    success: function (html) {
        // your code here
        $(".select2").select2(); // init the select
    }
```