# Bootstrap 4 Select2 jQuery Not working in Ajax Calls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using Bootstrap 4 and **Select2 jQuery plugin** in my webpage. It is working perfectly in my website. But when calling an another page contenting Select2 class of select input is not working.

Plugin Initiated at main page as -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()
    $('.select2-selection').css('border','0px')
    $('.select2-container').children().css('border','0px')

    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2bs4').select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap4'
    })
})
</script>
```

My Ajax page contain below input elements -

```
<select class="select2" style="width: 100%;" id="emp" name="emp">
<option value="">-- Select employee --</option>
<option value="E001">Employee 1</option>
<option value="E002">Employee 2</option>
</select>
```

I am unable to figure out the issue why it not working on Ajax Called page. Anybody please give answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this one related your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674228/select2-jquery-plugin-not-working-after-ajax-calling-for-html-content-change

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried your reference but still not working for my case. Can you please post an answer with code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you can call the select2 plugin function again after ajax called, I think.
Try it, maybe the mistake fixed.
Hope it helps. thanks

Comment: Thank you my friend. It works now. I called / initiated the select2 plugin along with the Ajax call as you suggested and got it working perfectly!!!