# Getting Select2 Gem to work with ActiveAdmin "Add New" Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-select2

I have a RubyOnRails Application that uses the ActiveAdmin and Select2 Gems. Right now, I have made a search box that after typing two letters, shows possible options from the set given. Here is the code for that:

```
f.has_many :location_permissions, :allow_destroy => true, heading: 'Users With Access To This Installation' do |app_f|
  app_f.input :user,  :input_html => { :class => "user_select" }, :collection => User.all.map{ |user| ["#{user.name} (#{user.email})", user.id] }
end
```

This also creates an "Add New" button below. When the button is clicked, a regular ActiveAdmin dropdown menu appears, but I want the Select2 search menu created above to show up. How do I do this?

Here is the user_select function:

```
$('.user_select').select2({
  minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

If I click the add new button, so it creates a new form, save that empty field, and then refresh the page, the new form becomes the Select2 search form I want. This leads me to think that Select2 applys its JS and CSS on page load, so is it possible to load that part of the page again through AJAX or some other mechanism? I have no idea how to do so, so if anyone could point me at a resource to do something like that, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work with the following code:

```
$(document).on('has_many_add:after', ->
  $('select.user_select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2
  })
)
```

This is in Coffeescript but the Javascript form of this is very similar, replace the "->" with function(){} . ActiveAdmin has an EventListener called `has_many_add:after` that is called some time after the button is clicked, and you need to execute your code after this. The code above works since the event can still bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, typically select2 is initialized at page load, which is exactly why you're seeing the behavior you described.

What you're going to need to do is wrap the initializer in another function that gets called after you click the 'Add New' button. I'm unfamiliar with ActiveAdmin, but assuming it's just an AJAX request to add to the form, something like this should work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setupSelect2();
});
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  setupSelect2();
});

function setupSelect2() {
  $('.user_select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2
  });
});
```

Put all of that in some external js file, include it in `application.js`, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Do you know how to include the file in application.js? I put the files in an external file called "searching.js" and tried adding //= require searching . This is the format the other files are included (ex. //= require jquery).

Comment: As long as `searching.js` is in `app/assets/javascripts` (the same folder `application.js` is in), that should work perfectly.

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder and it doesn't look like its working. Does the second function call (".ajaxComplete") call the setupSelect2 function whenever any AJAX request completes?

Comment: Yes, like I said I'm unfamiliar with ActiveAdmin, but when you click "Add New" some event is triggered. You want to capture that event, and at the end of its execution, call `.select2()` again. I assumed it was an AJAX call, but apparently that's not the case. See if you can find some docs for what is actually occurring when you click the button.

Comment: `$(".button.has_many_add").click(*function goes here*))` triggers when the button is pressed. If I put your code block in setupSelect2() inside there, it returns `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_location_location_permissions_attributes_0_user_id` . I think the `$('.user_select')` part doesn't work in this area, do you have any idea why this error is happening?

Comment: Could you post the code for that entire function? Anything relevant to the Add New button.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the HTML code generated: [link](http://pastebin.com/ZdySgpvv) . Ill try getting you something more from the docs since the button is autogenerated by the code I initially posted.

Comment: For my particular scenario, I have to write it in CoffeeScript, but I can take anything in JavaScript and figure out how to convert it into CoffeeScript. Here is the pastebin : [link](http://pastebin.com/zq5UGymq)

Comment: I believe the web page executes this piece of JavaScript accordingly (after being converted from CoffeeScript) [link](http://pastebin.com/QgpSLWzv)

Comment: In regards to your earlier error [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483348/query-function-not-defined-for-select2-undefined-error) appears to have a solution. Try using `$('select.user_select').select2()`

Comment: It almost works! What is happening is that the select2() load is getting called before the html is added, so nothing initially happens, but when I press the add new button again the old button switches to the proper look. Do you have any ideas make my code execute at the end? Are you familiar if JavaScript / CoffeeScript has threads so that I can separate into two threads and call a wait function on the thread with my select function?

Answer (score 0):

from the solution provided in this [ActiveAdmin issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/340#issuecomment-340891891)

we see how to call javascript / jQuery using ActiveAdmin, for a one off use.  Other answers provide ways to include `.js` files into the ActiveAdmin config.

here is a code snipit for implementing the OP's own solution with [Arbre](https://activeadmin.github.io/arbre/) the HTML builder syntax that is used within ActiveAdmin:

```rb
script do
  raw %(
    $(document).on('has_many_add:after', () =>
      $('select.user_select').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 2
      })
    )
  )
end
```

This felt helpful since for those who may not be familiar with how to implement JS in ActiveAdmin pages as an option to implement the selected Answer.