# Jquery select2 custom javascript function when searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have severall select2 in my page.
I have a specific ajax engine and can't change it for many reasons.
i would like to fill each select2 dropdown when the end-user type in the field, and use home made javascript to fill the "options" in the select2.

I've tried many different things found on the net, and can't find a working syntax for that.

For instance :

```
      jQuery("customer").select2({
          query: function (options) {
              alert('ok');
              // my ajax call would be here
              xajax_getCustomers(stringFilled);
          }
      });
```

i've tried with "ajax:" and several other things, i can't find how to trigger a javascript function when something filled.
Important : i should be able to get the string filled, in order to pass it to my ajax call

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax  You don't need to make your custom function, `select2` plugin comes with this feature integrated.

Comment: I already saw those informations. But it's for a "standard" ajax call with JSON. this is not my case. i want to be able to call my own javascript function

Comment: I add an answer with that. Tell me if it solves your problem

Comment: What version of select2 are you using? 3.5.x or 4.0.x?

Answer (score 5):

You have got this event:

```
  $(selector).on("select2-highlight", function(e) {
      console.log("highlighted val=" + e.val + " choice=" + e.choice.text);
  })
```

It's valid for a search event, so when `select2-highlight` event is fired means that user is searching for a string that you can manage with the `e.val` and `e.choice.text` values.

Unfortunatelly there's no strict search event, but you can bind the hided input text of the plugin with a `on('keyup');`

Something like this:

```
 $('input.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function() {
      alert($(this).val()); // it alerts with the string that the user is searching
 });
```

Comment: i've tried below code and this works, i get the string filled, BUT i don't know which select2 it refers to. any idea to know it ?


`jQuery(document).on("keyup",".select2-input", function (event) {
            alert(jQuery(this).val());
        });
`

Comment: Change `document` with your selector. If you have a select with `id="mySelect"` this converts to: `jQuery('#mySelect').on('keyup', '.inputclass', .... );`

Comment: doesn't work if i put the select id instead of document.

Comment: not the `<select>` id, I reffer to `<div class="select2 ... " id="mySelect">`

Comment: Then i probably have another problem : i do it with a classical select, but it doesn't work if i use a simple div instead. If i do :
`jQuery("#customer").select2();` 
i receive an error "Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 customer"  (jquery 3.5.2)
Then i'm stuck...

Comment: Yes, it happens when you try to initialise a select that there was initialised before, because it wraps the new div with the same properties as the native `<select>` tag. So to avoi that, you need to initialise only the native select, adding it to the selector: `jQuery("select#customer").select2()`. By this mode the selector is not ambiguous and I guess there are only one element with that ID. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14483350/5035890

Comment: This answer contains code from both Select2 3.x and Select2 4.x, that's why it's not working.