# How do i use onkeyup event in bootstrap select element?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

This bootstrap code filters but i would like to trigger `onkeyup` event and use it to run a function. As i type in the search input i would like it to trigger a `myFunction()`

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col-md-4">
            <label>Select</label>
            <select class="form-control select2 ">
               <option>Select</option> 
               <option>Car</option> 
               <option>Bike</option> 
               <option>Scooter</option> 
               <option>Cycle</option> 
               <option>Horse</option> 
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.select2').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery select2 custom javascript function when searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451524/jquery-select2-custom-javascript-function-when-searching).

Answer (score 0):

I finaly figured it out. Bootstrap Select doesn't directly expose an onkeyup event for its live search input box. To achieve this functionality, you'll need to target the appropriate element and attach the event listener yourself.

**1. Identify the Input Element:**
The live search input box bears the class `bs-searchbox input`. Use this selector to target it for event handling.
**2. Attach the `onkeyup` Event Listener:**

Employ jQuery to bind the `onkeyup` event to the input element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', '.custome_class .bs-searchbox input', function() {
        // Your code to execute on keyup
    });
});
```

Html

```
<select class="form-control custome_class ">
               <option>Select</option> 
               <option>Car</option> 
               <option>Bike</option> 
               <option>Scooter</option> 
               <option>Cycle</option> 
               <option>Horse</option> 
            </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input matInput type="text" (keyup.enter)="your function()"  autocomplete="off"  >
```

Use like this wherever you want to use.
`keyup.enter`. I used in my project just like this.

Comment: If you render this code you will see that there is a select element and an input field.