# How to dynamically replace some field in Flask-Admin into Select2?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, flask-admin

I have a flask-admin form, where when user select the topmost dropdown field, certain fields in this form must change into Select2 (dropdown) field. This is what I have so far:

```
for(var idx in formData.custom_field_chooser)
    {
        var custom_field = $('#' + idx);
        custom_field.select2(); //This generate error
    }
```

I think my code is correct, but that `custom_field.select2()` code geneate this error `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 undefined`.

Now, I am sure Select2 has already been included by `flask-admin` (cmiiw), but how do we use that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally looking at the trivial error message `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2`, [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483348/query-function-not-defined-for-select2-undefined-error) solved my problem. This is how you properly initialized an empty Select2:

```
custom_field.select2({
 data: {
   id: "",
   text: ""
  }
 });
```

This will change that `custom_field` element into `select2`.