# select2 tag box does not work once loaded through onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

In my page there is a `select` box that uses [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) library. All I want to do is to add more of the select box once a button is clicked. For this I tried the below code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application.css"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="location_form">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
                <label for="cat" class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">Category <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control input-transparent select2" id="cat" name="category" required="required" multiple="multiple" size="1" data-parsley-trigger="change">
                        <option style="margin-bottom: 1px;">Select Categories</option>
                        <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add More" />
        <div class="locations"></div>

        <script src="js/action-scripts.js"></script>
        <script>
            //----- tag loader --//
            $(".select2").each(function(){
                $(this).children().first().remove();
                $(this).select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Categories",
                    maximumSelectionSize: 4
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My **action-script.js** looks like the below:

```
// Add location 2
$('#addmore').click(function() {

    index = Math.random();
    var location_div = '<div class="location" id="location_' + index + '">';
    location_div += $('#location_form').html();
    location_div += '<hr class="col-sm-offset-1"></div>';
    $('.locations').append(location_div);
});
```

So, basically what Im trying to do is, once the button with id `#addmore` in my HTML page is clicked, I will append everything inside the `<div id="location_form">` div to `<div class="locations">`.

This works, however, the problem is I loose all the functionalities of the `select2` library in my new select-boxes. Here's my jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/0cars6oy/4/

If you check the above jsfiddle link you will see the select-boxes that appears after clicking the `Add More` button does not work. Doesn't matter what you type in there it wont suggest anything from the list.

My knowledge with javascript is very limited. I am having hard time figuring out how to fix this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: why is my question negative voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things mainly:

1) Remove id from the current select, since you are copying html directly.
2) Call this in the button click event handler, after adding html

```
$(".select2").each(function(){
                $(this).children().first().remove();
                $(this).select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Categories",
                    maximumSelectionSize: 4
                });
            });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I tried as per your instruction in my local machine however it didnt seem to work. I rather came up with some wired errors like `Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_autogen1`. Can you verify if your proposed solution works in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks this actually worked. I was having that issue because I named my class as select2. I found the solution for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483348/query-function-not-defined-for-select2-undefined-error

Comment: @KamrulKhan this is not problem, i updated your fiddle with this class and its worked...

Answer (score 1):

try this...i cant add inline jsfiddle because your styles is very large [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cars6oy/10/)

```
var index  =  1;
$('#addmore').click(function() {
        var _html = $('#location_form').clone(false);
    _html.find(".select2").prev('.select2-container').remove();
    var _id = 'location_' + index;
    $('<div/>', {
        class: 'location',
      id: _id,
      html: _html.html() + '<hr class="col-sm-offset-1"></div>',
    }).appendTo('.locations').find('select.select2').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Categories",
        maximumSelectionSize: 4
    });
    index++;
});


    $(".select2").children().first().remove();
    $(".select2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Categories",
        maximumSelectionSize: 4
    });
```